# Analytical Fourier Transforms with convolution rule

Tags: symbolic, fourier-analysis, convolution

The task is the following, how to extend Mathematica's FourierTransform command in order to be able to analytically deal with non-linear differential equations. To do so it should be able to deal with convolutions and derivatives

One way of dealing with complicated non-linear Partial Differential Equations is to transform them to Fourier space, where the products  become convolutions. However the FourierTansform command does not transform products into convolutions. The command

`FourierTransform[f[x,y]g[x,y],{x,y},{kx,ky}]`

Should result in something like

`Convolution[f[qx,qy]g[qx,qy],{qx,qy},{kx,ky}]`

I tried to create an extension that (robustly) allows this but failed.

Furthermore, in order to deal with PDE's the extension should also be able to deal with derivatives, such that

`FourierTransform[D[f[x,y],x]g[x,y],{x,y},{kx,ky}]`

results in

`Convolution[qx f[qx,qy]g[qx,qy],{qx,qy},{kx,ky}]`

I think such an extension would be extremely useful, but unfortunately FourierTransform is not very good at recognizing derivatives, and can simply not at all recognize convolutions...

any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Code something, if I t works, well done, if not, post your code and associated question... otherwise, this has a pre-order feel about it.

Comment: You are aware that `Convolve[]` is built-in?

Comment: In addition to `Convolution` not being the correct name, your notation for the Fourier transforms should also be different. `f[qx, qy]` etc. is not the correct form. It would be the (inverse) `FourierTransform` of `f`, so the replacement by `Convolve` would lead to a more complex expression than before. I.e., it's not a simplification, and there's no reason for *Mathematica* to do it.